# UnInstalling Programs By registry (UnistallString)

Tags: c#, uninstallation

I want to uninstall a software by using my code, my code is working on unistallString "msiexec.exe /x {your-product-code-guid}" and "C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe\".

but now working on uninstallString like "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe AIR\Versions\1.0\Resources\Adobe AIR Updater.exe -arp:uninstall"..

this throwing exception ("The system cannot find the file specified")

(Here S= MyUnistallString)

```
 try
        {
            s = s.Replace("\"", ""); //Replace <">

            string uninstallArguments = null;
            string uninstallAssembly = null;
            if (!s.Contains("/"))
            {
                uninstallAssembly = s;
            }

            else
            {
                string[] uninstallArgumentsArray = s.Split(new string[] { " /" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Split for any parameters
                if (uninstallArgumentsArray.Count() > 1)
                {
                    for (int count = 1; count < uninstallArgumentsArray.Count(); count++)
                    {
                        uninstallArguments = "/" + uninstallArgumentsArray[count];
                    }
                }
                uninstallAssembly = uninstallArgumentsArray[0];
            }


            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uninstallAssembly))
            {
                Process uninstallProcess = new Process();
                uninstallProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                uninstallProcess.StartInfo.FileName = uninstallAssembly;
                uninstallProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = uninstallArguments;
                uninstallProcess.Start();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,I've Found my mistake and it will also help others

Add this after

if (!s.Contains("/"))

```
if(s.Contains(" -"))
            {
                string[] uninstallArgumentsArray = s.Split(new string[] { " -" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Split for any parameters
                if (uninstallArgumentsArray.Count() > 1)
                {
                    for (int count = 1; count < uninstallArgumentsArray.Count(); count++)
                    {
                        uninstallArguments += " -" + uninstallArgumentsArray[count];
                    }
                }
```

this code works for all UnInstallString